# Regular expression python web scraping

Tags: python, regex, web-scraping, request, python-re

I am doing web scraping of this web site https://coronavirus.gob.mx/datos/
I made a successful **scrape** of this variables: "Confirmados", "Negativos", "Sospechosos" and "Defunciones" the code line for this variables are similar of this (please refer the code below)

`document.getElementById("gsPosDIV").innerHTML = (47144).toString().replace(/\\B(?=(\\d{3})+(?!\\d))/g, ",");`

I made this successful regular expression with the library requests and re :

`confirmados = re.search(r'document\.getElementById\("gsPosDIV"\)\.innerHTML = \((\d+)', raw_data).group(1)`

**This is my question**

For the variable "hospitalizados" this is de code line `document.getElementById("vHos").innerHTML = "39.15 %";` and I tried to built my regular expression similar to the other one, this is what I made:

`hospitalizados = re.search(r'document\.getElementById\("vHos"\)\.innerHTML =  \\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?%', raw_data).group(1)`

This is my output `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'` 
How can I build a right regular expression for the variable "hospitalizados"

Comment: web scraping, my favorite

Comment: is `r'document\.getElementById\("vHos"\)\.innerHTML =  \\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?%'` a regex of what is sought?

Comment: get the value of "vHosp" and keep on my variable "hospitalziados" I got the source code form this ```url = 'https://coronavirus.gob.mx/datos/Overview/info/getInfo.php' ```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
raw_data = 'document.getElementById("vHos").innerHTML = "39.15 %";'

print(re.search(r'^document\.getElementById\("vHos"\)\.innerHTML\s+=\s+"(\d+.\d+)', raw_data).group(1))

39.15
```

Comment: This is a chunk of my data_raw ```document.getElementById("pbFem").style.width = "0%";document.getElementById("vHos").innerHTML = "0%";document.getElementById("vAmb").innerHTML = "0%"; ```` your solution looks good but on my data_raw is not working

Comment: How does output look like for the above data ?

Comment: ```print(re.search(r'^document\.getElementById\("vHos"\)\.innerHTML\s+=\s+"(\d+.\d+)', raw_data).group(1))AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'```